# SSRS - Can you compute a difference between 2 different Tabllixes?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

[image: SSRS Tablixes and Design]

Hi all,

Is it possible to calculate a difference between two different tablixes in an SSRS like the below and show in the 'Delta' column in the top tablix?

I have included the design format as well (on the right)

Answer (score 0):

If both tablixes have the same DataSet you can just take the expression from tablix1 and the expression from tablix2 and calculate the difference.

For example:

```
'Expression Tablix1
=(Fields!Field1.Value / Fields!Field2.Value) + Fields!Field3.Value

'Expression Tablix2
=(Fields!Field4.Value * Fields!Field1.Value) - Fields!Field2.Value

'Differece from Tablix1 and Tablix2
=((Fields!Field1.Value / Fields!Field2.Value) + Fields!Field3.Value) - 
 ((Fields!Field4.Value * Fields!Field1.Value) - Fields!Field2.Value)
```